# Interfacing RJ45 to 3 pin RMII and bidirectionality

Tags: ethernet, rj45, network-interface, rmii

I am trying to add an Ethernet interface to a dev board ([This](https://www.nxp.com/design/development-boards/automotive-development-platforms/mpc57xx-mcu-platforms/mpc5775b-e-evb-low-cost-development-board-for-battery-management-and-inverter:MPC5775B-E-EVB) board specifically).

From looking at the schematics, I see that it has a 3 pin PHY input (GND, TRX+, and TRX-). From my understanding, a CAT5 cable has 4 wires essentially (RX+- and TX+- and both can be bidirectional).

So to interface this with say a RJ45 cable, do I just connect the TRX+ to the TX+ and TRX- to TX-, or the RX+ to TRX+ and RX- to TRX-? I'm sure I'm oversimplifying this and any guidance would be appreciated. I am planning on having the three wire board connect to another PCB that would have the RJ45 port and just wire the pins to the corresponding locations.

Comment: The board you mention has automotive ethernet, this wont directly connect to ‘normal’ ethernet. For ‘normal’ ethernet you’ll need a different PHY chip or some gateway/converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That PHY is for 100BASE-T1 (commonly known as "Automotive Ethernet" or BroadR-Reach), which is different from "standard" 100BASE-TX (FastEthernet) in that it uses a single pair for communication.

Converting it to 100BASE-TX involves using some sort of active media converter. It can of course be done, but if you do not want the 100BASE-T1 you are much better of just using a standard 100BASE-TX PHY to begin with.

Comment: Dang, I guess my eyes only read part of the sheet (missed the T1 vs TX). Thanks for pointing that out. Sounds like I need to find a BroadR-Reach to FEC device? is that a thing or do you recommend a way? I would use the standard phy, but on the board, it only comes with the T1

Comment: @bchang32 Maybe you could use something like this, if you must use that specific board: http://www.nxp.com/RDDRONE-T1ADAPT Although it doesn't seem to be in stock anywhere. But it might give you a start to keep searching.

Comment: Thanks, I found that one while looking too, but I'll keep searching. Thanks for all the info and clarification (especially the T1 vs TX)

Answer (score 1):

The board has an automotive 100Base-T1 Ethernet interface which uses a single bidirectional pair. It is not RMII and it is not compatible with anything else than other 100Base-T1 devices. It is not possible to connect it to any other standard Ethernet interface which would use two pairs of CAT5 cable and 8P8C connectors for RJ45 interface like 100Base-TX.